# No file produced when resizing image with imagemagick on node

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

So my issue is basically what the title says. When I run resize on a set of images i get no error but I also get no images in the final directory. I made the permissions on the directory 777 just in case that was the issue. I can use imagemagick to read the metadata from the images but it won't resize them. Can you find a simple, or huge, mistake I've made?

```
var im = require('imagemagick');

im.resize({

        srcPath: srcPath,
        destPath: destPath,
        width: 256,
        height: 256

    }, function(err, stdout, stderr) {

        if (err) {

            console.log(err);

        } else {

            console.log("Image Resized");
        }

});
```

All I ever get out is "Image Resized" out on the console.

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry if this is vague or I missed something.

Comment: Are you sure destPath is correct?  Log it to the console and check.

Comment: That's what I thought at first too. I've checked srcPath and destPath numerous times to make sure that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like an idiot. The problem is the parameter is 'dstPath' not 'destPath'